# Could not open connection to the AWS ubuntu host, on port 22: Connect failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, connection, telnet, connection-refused

I try connecting to my "RUNNING" ubuntu AWS instance on AWS on port 22 (ssh) but it failed with the below error.

```
telnet 13.232.139.204 22
Connecting To 13.232.139.204...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed
```

Below is my AWS instance details:

[image]

Below is the Security group "launch-wizard-1" details:

[image]

Port 22 seems to have been allowed.

There is no explicitly firewall that we installed is what I remember nor could I verify now that I m unable to login.

Here are the VPC details.

[image]

[image]

Finally, here is the overall VPC overview:

[image]

As you see it is using VPC "rtb-de62d4b5" route details of which is below:

[image]

Here is the ACL details for the instance:

[image]

I have restarted the instance multiple times but did not help. Please kindly suggest.

Note: Session Manager is not setup for this AWS instance.

Comment: Can you create a new SG with the same whitelisting and attach that to the EC2 and remove the default(launch-wizard-1)? I know it doesn't make sense but I remember someone had the same issue and this method had worked.

Comment: @Riz i create a new SG which only one rule of ssh port 22 (did not create all the rules so as to not complicate things) and pointed it to the instance. Restarted the instance but still, I m unable to connect.

Comment: Can you show me which ami are you using? And please provide the Route Table and ACL as well

Comment: @AshBlake i provided ACL and route details in the original post. Please check.

Comment: Does ssh work instead of telnet?

Comment: ssh also does not work @DevangSanghani

Comment: The port for telnet is 23.

Comment: Check if the subnet is PUBLIC subnet. Means Internet Gateway is attached with your VPC and your subnet has a route to that internet gateway.

Comment: @HussainMansoor, Ip is public so it's in public subnet and you can see from the screenshot that route table has internet gateway for all traffic. Also telnet doesn't have a port... At this point I would think the issue is with OS. Can you check the logs for OS from the console if you see anything suspicious? Also, do you have another host where you can login to in the same vpc and use it as a bastionhost and try to access this EC2 via it's private ip?

Comment: @Riz i can confirm that the security group is fine and I m able to use the same security group to connect to a new instance. Now, that we have determined this how can I resolve any server-related changes/issues? please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below steps to recover and fix the instance.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/how-to-fix-ssh-issues-on-ec2-linux-instances-using-aws-systems-manager/

It took about 2 hours for the process to complete.

I'm now able to connect alright.